# Least Squares removing first $k$ observations Woodbury formula

Tags: least-squares, recursive-algorithms, pseudoinverse

Given the matrix $X_{n,p}$ from the least squares problem $$ \mathbf{X} \cdot \mathbf{\beta} =  z $$

Where the normal equation is:

$$ \mathbf{\hat{\beta}} = \left(\mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{X}\right)^{-1} \mathbf{X}^T  z $$

I was very happy when I found the existence of the [Woodbury matrix identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity) unfortunantly 
I am struggling to use it (don't know if it's possible) for my problem.

$$ {(A+UCV)}^{-1}=A^{-1}-A^{-1}U{(C^{-1}+VA^{-1}U)}^{-1}VA^{-1} $$

#### The Problem

I want to compute a new $(X^TX)^-1$ after removing the first $k$ rows of $X$. I heard maybe it's called the leave-one-out (k-out?) statistics.

I found that for the my case the Woodbury formula is something like:

$$ {((X^TX)+UCV)}^{-1}=(X^TX)^{-1}-(X^TX)^{-1}U{(C^{-1}+V(X^TX)^{-1}U)}^{-1}V(X^TX)^{-1} $$

where $+UCV$ should somehow subtract the first $k$ rows.

If someone can give some help or point to some direction or references.